# How to use cookie expire time?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I wrote this code for my login page:

```
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("a");
 cookie["name"] = (string)ddr["name"];
 cookie["phone"] = (string)ddr["phone"];
 cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
```

How can I use the cookie expire time in other pages to block users after 10 seconds?

Comment: Do you want change "Expires" in other page?

Comment: no I want if cookie is expire , user login again.

Comment: Creating the `HttpCookie cookie` object does nothing by itself. You need to send the cookie to the user. Show us the code where you're doing that.

Comment: Moreover, if you're implementing your own login system, **STOP**. There's a perfectly good one already built into ASP.NET, including cookie expiries. Use that instead.

Comment: how should I send the cookie to the user? I want to wrtite it myself!